# Oh-my-zsh "take" command - Is there an equivalent in Fish?

Tags: oh-my-zsh, fish

Oh-my-zsh has the `take` command which creates a directory and enters into it in one step. Is there an equivalent command for the fish shell?

I do know that I can do it with `mkdir newDir && cd newDir`, but I like the shorter, more convenient version that Oh-my-zsh provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not built-in, but very easy to reproduce:

```
function take
    mkdir -p "$argv[1]"; and cd "$argv[1]"
end

funcsave take
```

This will create a lazy-load function in `$HOME/.config/fish/functions/take.fish`.  By "lazy-load", we mean that the function isn't loaded when Fish starts, but only the first time you run the `take` command.  So it's always available, but only takes up memory when you run it.

Comment: I'd recommend `and cd` in case mkdir fails.

Comment: @glennjackman Great point - Thanks!  Edited.  Could probably go one step further and still `cd` if the directory already exists.  Not sure what the oh-my-zsh behavior is.